# Exchange 2007 mailbox reassignment

Tags: exchange-2007

I am trying to move a mailbox from one user account to another within a single AD domain.  We are using Exchange 2007.  I have followed these steps:

1. Disable the account
2. From "Disconnected Mailbox" container, connect to
   the new account
3. I get a success message

When I try to login to OWA using the new user account, I get this message:

*Outlook Web Access could not connect to Microsoft Exchange. If the problem continues, contact technical support for your organization.*

**Request**
Url: https://mail.somedomain.com:443/owa/default.aspx
User host address: 1.2.3.4

**Exception**
Exception type: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ConnectionFailedTransientException
Exception message: Cannot open mailbox /o=cgsexchangeorganization/ou=exchange administrative group (fydibohf23spdlt)/cn=recipients/cn=someuser.

NOTE: I changed some identifying information for security purposes.

I have tried multiple times and get to the same place.  When I login to OWA with old account, I get an error that the mailbox cannot be found, which makes total sense.  Does anybody have any ideas on this?  Thanks!

Comment: What does it happens if you set the new account on Outlook? Any errors? Do you get the error with this account only, or with any account you try? Is the "someuser" the new user, or the old one?

Comment: Haven't tried directly in Outlook yet.  Yes, only with this account.  Yes, someuser is the new user.  I'll try in Outlook directly to verify if the problem is specific to OWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just being impatient it seems.  With nothing new done, after about 1 hour, I tried again and it all worked out fine.  Without knowing the specifics of how Exchange 2007 works under the hood, it seems like it needed some time to finish processing the reassignment.  Thanks for all your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping/starting the Exchange services (or reboot the server)? Is the Exchange database mounted?

Comment: I'd rather not do that yet, namely because the server is in production and we have enough users on it that it would be disruptive.  If I have to, I will after hours, but it seems odd that I would need to though.

Comment: So, can I safely assume the Exchange database is mounted, and that more users have their mailbox in it, and they are not experiencing any problem? Also, "someuser" can successfully login on the domain, correct?

Comment: Just to be thorough, yes, the database was mounted and no other users had issues with mailboxes in that store.  Also, the user was able to authenticate into AD.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The offline adress list has to be rewritten, so Clients can find the moved mailbox.
Either patience or manual update through the mmc does the trick